# How to scale up image that is displayed by position from bigger image?

Tags: css

I have a div. This div displays an image. The image is displayed as a sprite cut from a bigger image like this:

```
.myDiv {
    background-image: url("myBiggerImage.jpg");
    background-position: -51px -798px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
}
```

The div is of 16x16 size. I would like to increase div size to 32x32 with the 16x16 piece cut out from myBiggerImage.jpg from place where it is now and scaled 2 times to fit 32x32 div.

How to acomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale):

```
someselector {
    -webkit-transform:scale(2);
    -moz-transform:scale(2);
    -o-transform:scale(2);
    -ms-transform:scale(2);
    transform:scale(2);
}
```

You can check out its support at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).